# ETS ordered_set and effective pagination

Tags: performance, erlang, pagination, ets

I keep `{Key, Value}` data in ETS `ordered_set` where `Key` is a datetime. It is pretty easy to select all items in the given time internal `[From, To]`.

Something like that:

```
ets:select(Tab, [{{'$1', '$2'}, [{'>=', '$1', From}, {'=<', '$1', To}], ['$2']}])
```

We have `Limit` parameter in `select()` function so we are able to limit a number of items to be selected. But how can I specify an offset?

As an input, my module receives time interval and page number. My goal is to return items for the specified time interval and page. Page size (`Limit`) is a constant. I can calculate an offset as

```
Offset = Limit * PageNumber - Limit
```

The question is how can I effectively select items for the given page only?

I know that `select()` function can receive `Continuation` parameter, but I have no state from the previous selection. I only have a page number.

Possible, I have to use other data structure. Please, recommend better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Even your first select is not effective because ets matching is not smart enough. Follow this [discussion](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2011-August/060481.html).

Comment: Is there any alternative data structure to do such selection in O(logN)? Maybe gb_trees?

Comment: @Stas: If you will use `next`+`lookup` Robert's advice you will end with same result as any other O(logN) structure. Only drawback is you need store last key on page to move further.

Comment: @Stas: `ordered_set` is O(log N), as is gb_trees. Gb_trees allows you to step over the table but you can only start at the beginning. How big is your table? This will determine which data structures are practical for you to use.